# C# Dice Roll - Assigning scores to values

Tags: c#, dice

Currently working on a project and need some help. Still relatively new to c#. I have created a dice rolling game in which 5 dice are rolled at once in turns between 2 players. What I am stuck on is checking through these values for a three of a kind and assigning points .For example, A player presses enter and one appears three times then the player should receive three points or if four appears three times then the player receives the points. I have tried lots of different methods using if statements and for loops but cant seem to get it working. My code is provided below.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Dice_v4
 {
class Game
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random RandomNum = new Random();
        Player[] player1 = new Player[5];
        Die[] myDie = new Die[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            myDie[i] = new Dice_v4.Die(RandomNum);
            player1[i] = new Dice_v4.Player();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)   // Number of players
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Name for Player {0}:", i + 1);
            string NewName = Console.ReadLine();
            player1[i].SetName(NewName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int j = 1; j < 20; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                myDie[i].roll();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the first dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the second dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber1());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the third dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber2());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fourth dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber3());
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Rolled:{1} on the fifth dice", player1[i].GetName(), myDie[i].GetTopNumber4());
                Console.WriteLine("Total Throws:{0}", j);
                Console.ReadLine(); }
        }
    }
}

class Die
{
    private int NumberTop1;                  //attributes
    private int NumberTop2;
    private int NumberTop3;
    private int NumberTop4;
    private int NumberTop5;
    int threepoints = 0;

    private Random RandomNumGenerator;

    public Die(Random RandomGenerator)       // constructor
    {
        RandomNumGenerator = RandomGenerator;        // initialises random number
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        NumberTop1 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        NumberTop2 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        NumberTop3 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        NumberTop4 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6);
        NumberTop5 = RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6);

        // generates random number  / / Number of dice to be rolled

        Console.WriteLine("\tTotal score = {0}", threepoints);

        }
    public int GetTopNumber()
    {
        return NumberTop1;          // Returns number on top which equals dice roll
    }

    public int GetTopNumber1()
    {
        return NumberTop2;         
    }

    public int GetTopNumber2()
    {
        return NumberTop3;
    }

    public int GetTopNumber3()
    {
        return NumberTop4;
    }

    public int GetTopNumber4()
    {
        return NumberTop5;
    }

}

class Player
{

    private string Name;

    public void SetName(string NewName)         // constructor
    {
        Name = NewName;                     // initalises name
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;                    // Returns name when called

    }
}

}
```

Comment: `I've tried lots of different methods but can't get it working` like what? Include it in your question please!

Comment: Also your Player class looks fine. But you could get rid of the getter and setter methods and just have `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: I deleted the older versions. Wasn't getting anywhere with them and thanks Kyle Rone

Comment: Did you mean to use 5-sided dice? If you look at the documentation for [Random.Next()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that the upper bound is exclusive, meaning `.Next(1, 6)` will generate a number that is either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: Yeah I did that on purpose

Answer (score 0):

Advice:

Whenever you have variables or properties called something1, something2, ... - you're probably doing something wrong, and you probably want to use a list, array, hashmap...

My idea here would be to add all numbers to a list and then perhaps iterate to make a dictionary where key is the dice value and value is the count. Or you can do something else, depending which format you need for later operations.

```
List<int> diceValues = new List<int>();
diceValues.Add(die.GetTopNumber());
diceValues.Add(die.GetTopNumber1());
diceValues.Add(die.GetTopNumber2());
diceValues.Add(die.GetTopNumber3());
diceValues.Add(die.GetTopNumber4());
```

Now that you have them in a list, you can do something like:

```
var values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var item in diceValues) {
    if(values.Keys.Contain(item)) {
        values[item]++;
    } else {
        values[item] = 1;
    }
}
```

After this loop you will have a list of Dictionary items where a key will be the dice value, and the value the number of dice with that value.

E.g. if someone threw two threes, and two deuces and one four, the dictionary would look:

Key: 2, Value: 2

Key: 3, Value: 2

Key: 4, Value: 1

By iterating through these you can later make a scoring system...

Comment: I was about to write something along these lines, adding that you can group the list by the value, even just using Linq, and depending on the number of dice in each group you can write some pretty simple logic to evaluate them - i.e. if you have 5 groups then all the dice are different, if any group contains four items... etc.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try adding this to my code and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove these properties all along and use a list or array instead.

You declare a list:

```
public List<int> Roles { get; private set; }
```

And your roll method can become:

```
public void roll()
{
     this.Roles = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                            .Select(i => RandomNumGenerator.Next(1, 6))
                            .ToList();

    // Check for three of a kind:
    bool threeOfAKind = this.Roles.GroupBy(i => i).Any(g => g.Count() >= 3);

    // rest of your logic

    Console.WriteLine("\tTotal score = {0}", threepoints);
}
```

Later you can access each individual roll by `this.Roles[numOfRoll]`

Comment: Just as a note, you might want to explain the LINQ in this answer. The OP said they were a newbie so I can bet they don't know much about using LINQ.

Comment: Can you explain how to use this please? tried to include this code in mine but not sure what each part does. Thanks

Comment: Of-course, which part is not clear to you? if it's the LINQ part, then i strongly recommend that you read some tutorials about it as it is a very important aspect of .net